# React Native - mapStateToProps called but no re-rendering

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I started React Native / Redux development for two weeks now, and i have some issues with the mapStateToProps and re-rendering.

Here are the facts :

- mapStateToProps is called correctly with the right state (the new one)
- render function is not called after the mapStateToProps
- I have already check the troubleshooting page of Redux about that, and i dont have mutable issue

Here is the code :

**Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Item, Input, Button, Text } from 'native-base';
import { signup } from './../actions/signup.action';

class Signup extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            confirmPassword: ''
        };
    }

    render() {
        console.log('rendering', this.props);

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Item rounded>
                    <Input placeholder='Email' onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email: text})} value={this.state.email} />
                </Item>
                <Item rounded>
                    <Input placeholder='Mot de passe' secureTextEntry={true} onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password: text})} value={this.state.password} />
                </Item>
                <Item rounded>
                    <Input placeholder='Confirmation du mot de passe' secureTextEntry={true} onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({confirmPassword: text})} value={this.state.confirmPassword} />
                </Item>
                <Button rounded onPress={(e) => this.onSignup(this.state.email, this.state.password)}>
                    <Text>Créer un compte</Text>
                </Button>

                <Text>{this.props.isSignupLoading}</Text>

                <Text>{this.props.signupError}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }

    onSignup = (email, password) => {
        this.props.signup(email, password);
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isSignupLoading: state.isSignupLoading,
        isSignupSuccess: state.isSignupSuccess,
        signupError: state.signupError
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        signup: (email, password) => dispatch(signup(email, password))
    };
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF",
    },
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Signup);
```

**Actions**

```
import { firebaseAuth } from './../config/firebase';

export const signupLoading = (isSignupLoading) => {
    return {
        type: 'SIGNUP_LOADING',
        isSignupLoading
    };
}

export const signupSuccess = (isSignupSuccess) => {
    return {
        type: 'SIGNUP_SUCCESS',
        isSignupSuccess
    };
};

export const signupError = (error) => {
    return {
        type: 'SIGNUP_ERROR',
        signupError: error.message
    }; 
};

export const signup = (email, password) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(signupLoading(true));
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(() => dispatch(signupLoading(false)))
            .then(() => {
                console.log("signup.action#signup success");
                dispatch(signupSuccess(true));
            }) 
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("signup.action#signup failed - " + error);
                dispatch(signupLoading(false));
                dispatch(signupError(error));
            });
    };
};
```

**Reducer**

```
const defaultState = {
    isSignupLoading: false,
    isSignupSuccess: false,
    signupError: null
};

const signupReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SIGNUP_LOADING': 
            return Object.assign({}, state, { 
                isSignupLoading: action.isSignupLoading
            });
        case 'SIGNUP_SUCCESS':
            return Object.assign({}, state, { 
                isSignupSuccess: action.isSignupSuccess
            });
        case 'SIGNUP_ERROR':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                signupError: action.signupError
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default signupReducer;
```

If you want more code about what i have done, ask me.

Thanks for your help.
Best regards.

Comment: Did you check to see if the state is actually updating? Try installing the redux dev-tools.

Comment: @MaxMillington I checked with a breakpoint inside mapStateToProps and the new state is the right one... Is that what you mean by using dev-tools (i already use it for breakpoints) ?

Comment: I meant this: https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools

The fact that `componentWillReceiveProps` isn't firing means that the update isn't actually happening, or the component isn't properly connected to the Redux store.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Currently having the same problem :/

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue as you. You should fix it by modifying your mapStateToProps as following. This is due to signupReducer/signupReducer/signupError is under signupReducer not state.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isSignupLoading: state.signupReducer.isSignupLoading,
        isSignupSuccess: state.signupReducer.isSignupSuccess,
        signupError: state.signupReducer.signupError
    };
};
```